Issues with auth0 when using spring-boot backend and angular front-end
I am trying to configure auth0 as an external login service. From the server side everything seems to be correctly set up as I can use the server throught the browser and the login redirect is working correctly and I can get the PRINCIPAL in the endpoints to check the user info.
However, when I try to link my front end application I keep getting CORS issues that I have tried for several weeks to solve but have been unable. From the backend I added a CORSFILTER that already is adding the correct headers to the reply:
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class MyCORSFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}
}

With this I can already see the redirect occuring to my auth0 page but is having the following CORS error:

the error 302 is occuring and I am not able to fix it.
I have added the front end applicaiton to the auth0 configurations (in both Allowed Web Origins and Allowed Origins (CORS))
My questions:
1 - Is there any config missing from my server that I still need to add?
2 - Is there something missing in the front end applicaiton to handle redirects that I need to include in order to be able to fix this?
I have checked several posts and tried different things but nothing seems to be working. I am not using the @EnableWebSecurity as this bypasses the auth0 authentication and uses the default spring one.
Any advice?

If you "can use the server through the browser and the login redirect is working", this probably means that it is configured as an OAuth2 client with oauth2Login. In that case, requests are authorized with a session cookie, not a Bearer token.
For this (same-site, http-only) cookie to be exchanged with the Angular app, both apps will need to have the same origin. So, the question is not how to configure cross origin, but how to achieve same origin for the the Angular assets and the backend (your REST API). For that, you have two main options:

Serve Angular assets from the backend (static resources or whatever). During development phase, you might use Angular dev server "proxy" feature (define a proxy.conf.json file).
Put a reverse proxy in front of both (from the browser perspective, both would have that single gateway as origin).

As a side note, you should consider configuring your REST API as a stateless resource server (instead of a stateful client with authorization code flow), and add an OAuth2 BFF between your single-page application(s) and your resource server(s). This does not remove the need for same origin, but you can use the BFF for that too. I wrote an article for that on Baeldung.

Thanks for the comment, I have some follow up questions:
1 - Doens´t this defeat a bit the purpose of using external logins like auth0? These apps are suppose to be easily integrated but in this case we will need to set up a proxy for the server + front-end.
2 -  Is there a way to avoid this proxy and correct some sort of configuration so that the front-end is able to avoid this cors issue?
3 - I am using spring security with auth2 but using auth0 configuration, will this be impacted?
Thanks in advance!

Also when we use the front end we can see that the reddirect is happening but something is going wrong with the reply of auth0 (check the print I provided of the network tab) doesn´t this mean this is more an issue in the auth0 configuration?

I already answered most of these questions in the linked article. There is even a Spring profile with configuration for Auth0 in the companion project. There is a distinction to make between the cross origin requests to the authorization server which must be configured to allow requests from your domain (localhost in the case of your dev machine), and the same origin requests between Angular assets and your REST API.
